# Docker WSL2 Nginx 404 Eror when trying to serve index.html or index.php file

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to access the nginx server from the Docker container, but I keep getting 404 error w/e I tried to do.

I have the docker files hosted in the linux sub system (\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-20.04\var\www\wp-test)

Inside this directory I have the following files and DIR's:

- config (DIR)
- wordpress (DIR)
- docker-compose.yaml

Inside the docker-compose.yaml I have the following configuration:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/wordpress
      - ./config/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
  php:
    build:
      context: ./config
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/wordpress
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./config/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/wordpress
volumes:
  mysqldata:
```

So as you can see the /config/site.conf is used for the nginx config.

Inside /config/site.conf I have the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name php-docker.local;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    keepalive_timeout 300s;
    root /var/www/wp-test/wordpress;

    location / {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
        # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location ~ /.php$ {
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

}
```

So the root is set to /var/www/wp-test/wordpress, and it tries to access index.html

inside /var/www/wp-test/wordpress i have the both index.php and index.php
I set the wordpress folder to 777 just to make sure its accessible from anywhere.

But I keep getting 404 error when I try to access localhost:8000.

Any idea what could be wrong with my project?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are mounting the local `./wordpress` to `/var/www/wordpress` in the container in both your `web` and `php` services and not `/var/www/wp-test/wordpress`. Try mounting it to `/var/www/wp-test/wordpress` you can verify this by getting inside the container and check that the directory `/var/www/wp-test/wordpress` indeed has your files / folders.
Or you can just change the root directory to `/var/www/wordpress` inside your nginx conf file.

Comment: You are right, I modified the mounts to /var/www/wp-test/wordpress now, but sadly this did not fix the issue. In wsl when i go to /var/www/wp-test/wordpress and i do a ls -al I get the following output :
mohammad@workmhe01:/var/www/wp-test/wordpress$ ls -al
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data       46 Aug 31 14:09 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data      405 Apr 13 12:52 index.php

Comment: did you try listing the same directory inside the container? What is the output of `docker exec -it <nginx container id or name> ls -l /var/www/wp-test/wordpress`?

Comment: I did run sudo docker exec -it d30fa406282f9ac709011d8a2ae5a46c9620e3c255bafa9635890704cd32761a ls -l /var/www/wp-test/wordpress

And I got the following output:

ls: cannot access '/var/www/wp-test/wordpress': No such file or directory

so it seems that it can not find the /var/www/wp-test/wordpress dir inside the nginx container, any idea why?

Comment: Looks like the volumes are not getting mounted properly, recheck your directory paths that are mounted and also check by opening the container shell with `docker exec -it <nginx container id or name> sh`

Comment: connected to the container via the command you provided and yeah i only had /var/www/wordpress instead of /var/www/wp-test/wordpress. I then deleted the containers and run docker-compose up -d again. Now inside the nginx container i can see /var/www/wp-test/wordpress. But when I access the browser on localhost:8000 it downloads some file instead of rendering the page. Any idea why?

Comment: Update: managed to serve the index.html file after I edited the site.conf.

Original config:
server {
    index index.php index.html;

I noticed it tries to open index.php first, so i switched the spots between index.php and index.html.

server {
    index index.html index.php;

and now it serves my index.html file. Thanks a lot for the help. I will try to figure out how to serve also the php file but that's another topic. Thanks.